# VB Position of Picture Box in Snakes and Ladders

Tags: vb.net

```
    Private Sub BTNP1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNP1.Click
        RollDice()                  'dice rolling sub'
        P1Pos = P1Pos + Dice + 1    'decides position based on dice roll'
        Label1.Text = P1Pos
        If P1Pos < 10 Then
            P1x = 214 + (P1Pos * 60)      'Gets position and moves the PB (of size 60px) another 60px along from side'
            P1Point = New Point(P1x, 570) 'Creates a new point with the new x value'
            PBP1.Location = P1Point       'changes the location of the picture box'
        ElseIf P1Pos > 9 And P1Pos < 20 Then
            P1x = 754 - ((P1Pos - 10) * 60)
            P1Point = New Point(P1x, 510)
            PBP1.Location = P1Point
        ElseIf P1Pos > 19 And P1Pos < 30 Then
            P1x = 214 + ((P1Pos - 20) * 60)
            P1Point = New Point(P1x, 450)
            PBP1.Location = P1Point
        ElseIf P1Pos > 29 And P1Pos < 40 Then
            P1x = 754 - ((P1Pos - 30) * 60)
            P1Point = New Point(P1x, 390)
            PBP1.Location = P1Point
        ElseIf P1Pos > 39 And P1Pos < 50 Then
            P1x = 214 + ((P1Pos - 40) * 60)
            P1Point = New Point(P1x, 330)
            PBP1.Location = P1Point
        ElseIf P1Pos > 49 And P1Pos < 60 Then
            P1x = 754 - ((P1Pos - 50) * 60)
            P1Point = New Point(P1x, 260)
            PBP1.Location = P1Point
        ElseIf P1Pos > 59 And P1Pos < 70 Then
            P1x = 214 + ((P1Pos - 60) * 60)
            P1Point = New Point(P1x, 200)
            PBP1.Location = P1Point
        ElseIf P1Pos > 69 And P1Pos < 80 Then
            P1x = 754 - ((P1Pos - 70) * 60)
            P1Point = New Point(P1x, 140)
            PBP1.Location = P1Point
        ElseIf P1Pos > 79 And P1Pos < 90 Then
            P1x = 214 + ((P1Pos - 80) * 60)
            P1Point = New Point(P1x, 80)
            PBP1.Location = P1Point
        ElseIf P1Pos > 89 And P1Pos < 94 Then
            P1x = 754 - ((P1Pos - 90) * 60)
            P1Point = New Point(P1x, 20)
            PBP1.Location = P1Point
        ElseIf P1Pos > 93 Then
            P1Distance = 100 - P1Pos   'gets distance from end of board'
            If P1Distance >= Dice + 1 Then     'aks if the distance is = or >  the dice roll'
                P1x = 754 - ((P1Pos - 90) * 60)
                P1Point = New Point(P1x, 20)
                PBP1.Location = P1Point
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

my picture box character always stops at 94 or closer to 100 but never actually moves again once in this position. I'm trying to get the picture box to stay still unless it is able to move without exceeding 100. this is the only way I can think of doing it and it has worked in past iterations but I cannot get it to work here.

P.S. I can't use a different language because VB is required by my school for this project.

Comment: This looks like [tag:VB.Net], not [tag:vba]

Comment: Sorry I didn't know the difference but I'll update it, I'm using visual express 2012

Comment: You should read the tag info if you aren't sure what a tag means. Also, what happens after your box stops before the end of the field?

Comment: The code has `If P1Distance >= Dice + 1`, but what about `If P1Distance < Dice + 1`? (P.S. You could take all the occurrences of `PBP1.Location = P1Point` out and add it just *once* after the `End If` to make the code shorter and easier to read.)

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the checking for the game win separate from the movement of the player's piece.

Also, you could calculate the location of the player's piece, which would cut out many of the ["magic numbers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) used.

```
Option Strict On

Dim rand As New Random()

Dim P1Pos As Integer = -1

Private Function DieRoll() As Integer
    ' Return a random number from 1 to 6 inclusive.
    Return rand.Next(1, 7)
End Function

Private Sub BTNP1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNP1.Click
    Dim currentSquare = P1Pos
    Dim numberRolled = DieRoll() ' 1..6

    Dim provisionalSquare = currentSquare + numberRolled

    If provisionalSquare <= 100 Then
        currentSquare = provisionalSquare
    Else
        ' Perhaps indicate that the number rolled was too high, so no move.
        MessageBox.Show("Rolled too high!")
    End If

    If currentSquare = 100 Then
        ' I guess you want to do something here
        Exit Sub
    End If

    P1Pos = currentSquare

    Dim row = currentSquare \ 10
    Dim col = currentSquare Mod 10

    Dim direction = 1 - ((row Mod 2) * 2)   ' ltr=1 rtl=-1

    If direction = -1 Then
        col = 9 - col
    End If

    Dim x = 214 + 60 * col
    Dim y = 510 - 60 * row

    PBP1.Location = New Point(x, y)

End Sub
```

The calculations for `x` and `y` are just what I guessed at from the code in the question.

If this is for homework, you need to make sure that you understand what is happening in the code and be able to explain it. Some study of what is going on using the debugger to watch the values of variables will go a long way to helping you with that and your future endeavours ;)